# In SQL, what does ALL SELECT TOP 1 NULL,NULL do?

Tags: sql

I have this end of SQL query that i don't understand: `UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 NULL,NULL`

Could someone explain it step by step?

Cheers

Comment: Check out `UNION ALL` (incl NULL), and MS SQL Server's `TOP`.

Comment: This is only a fragment of a larger query.  Can you post the entire query or at least a representative sample of it?

Answer (score 0):

You did not "parse" the query correctly: `ALL` belongs to `UNION`, as in `UNION ALL`, not to `SELECT`.

The portion `SELECT TOP 1 NULL, NULL` of the query simply adds a row with two `NULL` columns to the result of `SELECT` above `UNION ALL`. You can drop `TOP 1` if you would like to, because it is unnecessary.

For example, if you have a query

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM User
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL
```

such query would produce a list of `FirstName, LastName` tuples from table `User` followed by a single tuple of two `NULL`s.

This trick may be useful so that the program receiving the data from your query could decide when to stop reading. The trick borders on the hack, however, because RDBMS is allowed to return the pair of `NULL`s produced by the bottom portion of `UNION ALL` before, after, or in the middle of other names.

Comment: The top is unnecessary here.

Comment: @sagi Of course it is. My understanding is that someone wrote this query, and OP is trying to make sense of it. Whoever wrote the query put `TOP 1` into it, so I might as well keep it there.

Comment: I'd be careful with *the program receiving the data from your query could decide when to stop reading* as there is no guarantee, that this added tupel will be the last row in the result set...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I've done such things (e.g. adding "column captions") by creating a `ROW_NUMBER()` on the *big* resultset and add a "0" or a *very big number* to the added row. This as a sub-select and ordered by this number will put the added line either in the first or in the last place...